# array_diff check values from one array against keys from another

Tags: php, arrays

There's `array_diff()`, which checks values from one array against values from another. Then there's `array_diff_key()` which checks keys from one array against keys from another. Is there a core function, or a non-looping way to check if there are values from one array that are not keys in another, and return those values back in an array? The function needs to check for keys that are either associative or sequential.

E.g.:

```
function somefunction($values, $keys)
{
    // hopefully no loops
    return $array;
}
$keys = array(1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three');
$values = array(1,3,5);    
print_r(somefunction($values, $keys);
```

Would return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
)
```

And:

```
$keys = array('ingmar'=>'bergman','jim'=>'jarmusch','wim'=>'wenders');
$values = array('jim','wim','john');    
print_r(somefunction($values, $keys);
```

would return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'john'
)
```

Basically I need the fastest way to do this.

Comment: Also, what methods have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)** to produce a new numerical array of the keys.

```
array_diff($array1, array_keys($array2))
```

Comment: Of course! Staring me in the face. Thanks so much. Will accept in ten minutes.

Comment: And you can wrap it in array_values too, if you want the result to be reindexed.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a combination of array_flip and array_diff to compare. Array_flip will make all of your keys values and values keys.